# How to Fix VSCode Syntax Highlighting for Variables Python

Tags: python, variables, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

In VSCode, my syntax highlighting for variables occasionally disables. After experimentation, it seems to happen mostly when I'm working on WSL. I haven't found a solid way to recreate it, but I've noticed it happening (not all the time, but sometimes) when performing any action that would temporarily render the variable as plaintext/not a variable. For example, temporarily removing the "=" when defining the variable.

To fix it, I can restart/reload VSCode, but it just gets pretty inconvenient considering it happens once every 30 minutes, if not more often. My theme is Dark+ and it normally looks like the first image (blue highlighted variables), but whenever this bug happens, it looks like the second (unhighlighted; white text).

It also happens when defining functions. Not sure if it happens to anything else at this point.

I've tried resetting my VSCode, reinstalling all extensions, deleting the "Code" folder in %appdata%, as well as deleting ".vscode" in %userprofile%.

When I hover over the variable, it is still recognized as a variable; it just is not highlighted.

My extensions are:

C/C++
C#
Discord Presence
GitHub Pull Requests and Issues
gitignore
HTML CSS Support
isort
Jupyter
Jupyter Cell Tags
Jupyter Keymap
Jupyter Notebook Renderers
Jupyter Slide Show
Live Server
Pylance
Python
GitHub Codespaces
WSL

What it looks like when the bug happens

[image: img]

What it should look like

[image: img]

Comment: If you only keep python extension, will the problem occur?

Comment: Read [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775038/visual-studio-code-syntax-highlighting-not-working), This is probably caused by extension conflicts. You can install extensions one by one to find problems

Comment: Does this still occur to you? Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Also what version of the WSL extension you have.