# Change Color/Lint in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm a novice and you'll probably roll your eyes at my question, but - is there any way to change/enhance the coloring-scheme in Visual Studio Code?

If you look at my screenshot. To the left is website where I'm currently learning the basics. .pop./.append and many other things are colored in a more convenient way (for me, that is). Can I get that in VSC as well? How?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN3FR.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get VS's python syntax highlighting in VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291759/how-can-i-get-vss-python-syntax-highlighting-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

About **Changing Color Themes**, please refer to [Selecting the Color Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_selecting-the-color-theme) in official docs.

About **Syntax Highlighting**, you can install `Pylance` in extension marketplace and set it as python language server in `Settings.json`:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```